# Python won't overwrite 777 file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a script that is outputting the pid.  I change permissions to 777.  Every subsequent instance will overwrite this file with the new pid. Despite the 777 permissions, python reports an OS Error that the operation is not permitted unless the user executing the script is the owner of the file.  (I can delete/overwrite the file from the shell, of course).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time

f = open("/tmp/test.txt", 'w')
f.write("Hello, file!\n")
os.chmod("/tmp/test.txt", 0777)
f.close()

$ /tmp/myscript.py # fine
$ sudo -u other_user /tmp/myscript.py #not fine -- gives error
```

Comment: Would running `os.chmod` before `f= open` help?

Comment: did you try running os.chmod after f.close(). It probably fails on an open file.

Comment: Is the `OSError` definitely caused by opening/writing to the file? I would think `os.chmod` would fail for any user except the file's owner.

Comment: Which line has the error? Is the `open` failing?

Comment: Are you sure you have write and execute access to `/tmp`?

Comment: It was the chmod that was the error.  I totally missed that.  Thanks for thall of the input, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, only the user who created the file or root can change its permissions. If the file doesn't exist when you call `open`, you are the owner of the new file and can change its permissions. When the file already exists, it's just truncated and the existing permissions are still in effect. It would be reasonable to just catch and ignore the error because it only happens after the permissions were setup correctly.

If you have the proper permissions in the parent directory, you can delete the file and create a new one each time. But that doesn't work for /tmp because the sticky bit is set and only owner can delete the file.

Comment: You are right, but if the file was created by the script and *if the script worked as expected*, the file should be writable by anyone after first creation. I think the problem stated by miraculixx in comments is the actual cause.

Comment: Cheers -- this was it.  It's the chmod that's doing that.  I guess I need to only do that if I'm owner (which will be the person creating it the first instance).

Comment: @SergeBallesta - the file is writable (so future `open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w')` operations work) but changing metadata like file permissions is a different deal and is not governed by the file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

`$ /tmp/myscript.py` creates a file owned by you.

and `$ sudo -u other_user /tmp/myscript.py` means `other_user` is going to change the file permission owned by you.

same as the following situation:

```
account1$ touch /tmp/test.txt
account1$ chmod 777 /tmp/test.txt
su account2
account2$ chmod 777  /tmp/test.txt 
#chmod: changing permissions of `test.txt': Operation not permitted
```